# Match a line in python

Tags: python, string

I need to add an extra line in an existing xml file. I need to add a new line.
The existing xml files have the lines

```
 <serviceInstance name="idstore.ldap" provider="idstore.ldap.provider">
  <property name="idstore.config.provider" value="oracle.security.jps.wls.internal.idstore.WlsLdapIdStoreConfigProvider"/>
```

I need to add an extra line after these two lines.

So i have written a code which opens the source file and copies line by line to the new destination file.
In the for loop which copies i put a condition

```
for line in source:
    if line.strip().startswith('<property name=\"idstore.config.provider\"'):
        print 1                
        destination.write(line)
        destination.write('<property name=\"virtualize\" value=\"false\"/>')#
        continue
    else:
        print 2
        destination.write(line)
        continue
```

But the if condition is not matching the line and the condition is getting missed.
Could anyone point out how to resolve the issue.Any spaces at the beginning causing the error? 
I am new to python, excuse me if its a trivial question.

Comment: If it's an XML file, use an XML parser. You'll do yourself a favour in the long run.

Comment: Is it because of white spaces in front of the line? Try: `line.strip().startswith(...)`

Comment: @freakish I added strip () and removed the r. Still its now working.

Will regular expressions be of any help ?

Comment: @Shockeduser No, using regular expressions with XML is a heresy. What is that `[ ]*` in front of your string? Remove that.

Comment: And sorry for the tweaks in copying the code.Finding it hard to format properly to show it as a code

Comment: @Shockeduser Don't worry, happens all the time. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using `r` in front of your string. Python uses that flag to interpret the string literally, i.e.

```
r'test\"'
```

is exactly

```
'test\\"'
```

remove `r` or remove `\` in your string.